# How do I navigate with uialertiew?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I've decided to delete the button, and now want to navigate. The idea is simple; I want to, when I click ''Next Site'' be transfered to another site in the application. However I don't know how to do this.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace TableView
{
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    string[] tableItems;
    string cellIdentifier = "TableCell"; 



    public TableSource (string[] items)
    {
        tableItems = items; 
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return tableItems.Length; 
    }
    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Alert", "You selected: " + tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "Next Site", null).Show();
        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true); 
    }
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellIdentifier);
        cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row];

        if(indexPath.Row > -1)
            cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row - 0];



            return cell; 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: if the question is too vague, or written badly u can delete it or edit it.

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS8+, you should deal with `UIAlertController` instead.

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView is depricated since iOS 8 and should be replaced with UIAlertController. For an UIAlertController you can provide actions.

```
var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Title", "Message", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, ActionHandler));
```

Inside your ActionHandler you can switch to your new page.